# Inner Join в другую сторону.

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Предположим, у меня есть две таблицы в базе данных:

```
table1:
-id
-name
-status

table2:
-id
-parent_id
-name
-status
```

Индексы `table1.id` и `table2.parent_id` связаны. Вопрос заключается в следующем: как лучше всего получить все записи из таблицы `table1` у которой нет "детей" в таблице `table2`?

То есть если в таблице `table2` есть хоть одна запись `parent_id` которой совпадает с `table1.id`, то такая запись пропускается. Еще нужно, чтобы был определенный статус у первой и второй таблицах.

Знаю, что можно воспользоваться `left outer join`, повыбирать все записи, где остался NULL со второй таблицы:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
 (
  SELECT 
   table1.*,
   table2.id AS id2
  FROM 
   table1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   table2 
    ON table2.parent = table1.id
    AND table2.status = 'status2'
  WHERE
   table1.status = 'status1'
 ) AS tmp
WHERE
 ISNULL(id2)
```

Способ рабочий... Но... Костыль, мягко выражаясь. Есть ли возможность сделать как-то более человечно?

Comment: А почему бы сразу не написать `WHERE ISNULL(id2)` во внутреннем селекте? Тогда и внешний не нужен

Comment: Посмотрите картинки [здесь](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins). Там есть пример, который вам нужен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш способ и есть каноничный способ искать записи без дочерних. Разве что внешний запрос не нужен:

```
select table1.* 
from table1 left join table2 on table1.id = table2.parent_id
where table2.id is null
```

Но если хочется чего-то более явного, то вот вам такой вариант:

```
select * from table1
where id not in (select parent_id from table2)
```

Для старых СУБД такого варианта советовали избегать из-за его неоптимальности - но в современных СУБД оптимизатор запросов справляется.

Answer (score 1):

Left join и фильтрация тех записей, для которых не нашлось пары в table2:

```
select * from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.parent_id and table2.status = 'status2'
where t2.parent_id = null and table1.status = 'status1'
```

Comment: Тогда вопрос: чем отличается LEFT OUTER JOIN от LEFT JOIN?
Знаю, что это другой вопрос, но результат одинаковый в обоих случаях.

Comment: @vtvz_ru ничем, это синонимы. Слово `outer` было введено в противовес `inner` -- это соответственно внешняя и внутренняя часть на диаграммах Венна, ссылку на которые вам привели в комментарии к вопросу. Ну а поскольку добавки `left`, `right`, `full` и так отличают запрос от `inner`, `outer` разрешили опускать.